# Plotting iterations

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot on MATLAB 20 iterations of x_n=rx_(n−1)(1−x_(n−1)) by using:

```
r = 3;
x = 0.8;
MaxIter=20;
for r = R
     x = rand(1,N);
% iterate the logistic map
    for iter=1:MaxIter 
        x = r*x.*(1-x);
    end    
    X = [X; x];  % store the positions
    end

iter = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
figure; %// opens figure
hold on %// plots multiple things in one figure
plot(iter,X)
```

I am currently returning the error.

```
Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length.

Error in Untitled5 (line 16)
plot(iter,X)
```

My aim to observe which values this will oscillate between

Comment: Can you be a little more specific and provide the actual error message? What is `R`?

Comment: @Suever I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely you realize that you have *two* for loops and that your `plot` command is outside of both of them. The outer loop loops through `R` and the inner loop loops through your iterations.

The issue is that you keep concatenating new values onto `X` everything time you go through the outer loop, across multiple values or `r`. So `X` ends up being `numel(R) x N` by the time you get to the `plot` command. This obviously isn't the same size as `iter`.

For that reason, `plot` fails because it expects the first two inputs to be the same size.

You're not actually storing each iteration through the inner loop so I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to plot here.

Comment: I have tried to put plot inside the loop but I am still returning the same error!

Comment: @Nique please see my update. What is the size of `R` and what exactly do you want to plot?